# How do I connect to AMQ7 via JMX, programmatically to get broker metrics with MBean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmx, activemq-artemis

Our team just started testing AMQ7 and the application I implemented no longer connects to the broker since we migrated from AMQ6 to AMQ7. After reading over documentation I noticed the uri string is completely different then before where it doesn't need the service or rmi embedded in the uri to connect. Below is the code I'm using to connect but causing the errors.

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL must start with service:jmx:
      at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.<init>(JMXServiceURL.java:169) ~[na:na]
      at com.ups.aaa.doss.MsgAudtingRunner.run(MsgAudtingRunner.java:110) ~[classes/:na]
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
      at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

This is the code which the error happens at:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(brkerInfo.getValue());
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, environment);
```

Is there another Class I need to reference instead of JMXServiceURL which I know expects the uri to have service as a prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the example that ships with the broker in `examples/features/standard/jmx` ([also available in GitHub](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/examples/features/standard/jmx)). It demonstrates how to connect to the broker programmatically using JMX. It does, in fact, use `JMXServiceURL` and `JMXConnectorFactory` and the URL does use "service" and "rmi", e.g.:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Comment: Thank you, now that it's able to connect I'm having issues install the package for this any code examples that you can find?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Which package are you installing? Why do you need to "install" anything? The example code is in the example that I linked. What more do you need?

Comment: Yes, the URL you provided was indeed correct but I needed to download the artemis jar file for me to be able to connect to the broker properly